# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android

I have just installed Android Studio and copied 100s of images from my existing Eclipse Project in Android Studio 1.5 and got the error

```
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1627229642): libpng error: Not a PNG file
```

After searching a lot i have found

```
downgrade your libpng to version 1.5.x
```

will solve the purpose. I have no idea how to do it. Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to libpng-1.5.x is one solution, but a better solution is to fix the bad PNG files.  You can do that with any PNG editor that's built with libpng16; the bad iCCP chunk gets skipped and not copied to the output PNG.

Losing the bad iCCP chunk isn't harmful because most applications will assume the new unmarked PNG file is in the sRGB colorspace by default anyway.

You can use ImageMagick (convert in.png out.png or mogrify *.png), GraphicsMagick (gm convert in.png out.png), pngcrush (pngcrush in.png out.png), all of which are available for free), or others.  Disclaimer: I wrote pngcrush.

To "downgrade" libpng to libpng-1.5.x, you could build your application with libpng-1.5.x as a static library included in your project.  That is, either get a copy of libpng-1.5.x and copy its *.h and *.c files into your project and compile them together with your application, or build libpng15.a from libpng-1.5.x and link your application with that. The disadvantage of either of these is that you won't automatically get any libpng security updates.

Comment: The images are more than 100 for each density. I have to complete the app urgently. Right now downgrading will only help. I shall modify the images later on. Please suggest how to downgrade.

Comment: Any of the applications that I mentioned could fix 100's and 100's of images in a reasonable amount of time with simple batch commands like "mogrify *.png".  But see instructions that I added to the answer for "downgrading".  I really recommend fixing the images, though.